# SNI and Virtual Hosts with CNAMEs and SSL in NGINX

Tags: ssl, nginx, dns, cname, sni

For a long time, we have maintained a website that uses wildcard SSL to protect both the core site (https://www.OURSITE.com) and client-specific subdomains (https://CLIENT.OURSITE.com). To do this, we have have configured one virtual host for NGINX and everything was working swimmingly.

Recently, one client wanted to use their own domain to show CLIENT.OURSITE.com. I told them to create a CNAME record from www.CLIENTSITE.com to CLIENT.OURSITE.com. I then purchased and configured a separate SSL certificate for www.CLIENTSITE.com and created a separate vhost for it.

However, once you launch a browser and navigate to www.CLIENTSITE.com you always get an invalid common name SSL error as NGINX is serving the wildcard cert for OURSITE.com instead of www.CLIENTSITE.com. NGINX is correctly configured to use SNI.

The NGINX config for OURSITE looks like:

```
upstream app_server {
  server unix:/path/to/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen         80;
    server_name OURSITE.com;

    client_body_buffer_size 2K;
    client_header_buffer_size 2K;
    client_max_body_size 1K;
    server_tokens off;
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST|PATCH)$ )
    {
        return 444;
    }

    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen         80;
    server_name *.OURSITE.com;

    error_log /path/to/logs/nginx-error.log;
    access_log /path/to/logs/nginx-access.log;

    client_body_buffer_size 2K;
    client_header_buffer_size 2K;
    client_max_body_size 1K;
    server_tokens off;
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST|PATCH)$ )
    {
        return 444;
    }

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server {
    listen   443 ssl;
    server_name OURSITE.com;
    root /path/to/root/;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/OURSITE.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/OURSITE.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem;

    client_body_buffer_size 2K;
    client_header_buffer_size 2K;
    client_max_body_size 1K;
    server_tokens off;
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST|PATCH)$ )
    {
        return 444;
    }

    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen   443 ssl;
    server_name *.OURSITE.com;
    root /path/to/root/;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/OURSITE.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/OURSITE.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    client_body_buffer_size 2K;
    client_header_buffer_size 2K;
    server_tokens off;

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST|PATCH)$ )
    {
        return 444;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_types application/x-javascript text/plain text/css text/xml application/xml text/javascript application/json;

    error_log /path/to/logs/nginx-error.log;
    access_log /path/to/logs/nginx-access.log;

    location / {
        # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
        #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS, this helps Rack
        # set the proper protocol for doing redirects:
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
        # can be set properly within the Rack application
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;

        # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
        # Comet/long-poll stuff.  It's also safe to set if you're
        # using only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx.
        # Otherwise you _want_ nginx to buffer responses to slow
        # clients, really.
        # proxy_buffering off;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And the NGINX config for www.CLIENTSITE.com looks like:

```
upstream app_server2 {
  server unix:/path/to/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen         80;
    server_name www.CLIENTSITE.com;

    error_log /path/to/logs/client-nginx-error.log;
    access_log /path/to/logs/client-nginx-access.log;

    client_body_buffer_size 2K;
    client_header_buffer_size 2K;
    client_max_body_size 1K;
    server_tokens off;
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST|PATCH)$ )
    {
        return 444;
    }

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server {

    listen   443 ssl;
    server_name www.CLIENTSITE.com;
    root /path/to/root/;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/CLIENTSITE.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/CLIENTSITE.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    client_body_buffer_size 2K;
    client_header_buffer_size 2K;
    server_tokens off;

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST|PATCH)$ )
    {
        return 444;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_types application/x-javascript text/plain text/css text/xml application/xml text/javascript application/json;

    error_log /path/to/logs/client-nginx-error.log;
    access_log /path/to/logs/client-nginx-access.log;

    location / {
        # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
        #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS, this helps Rack
        # set the proper protocol for doing redirects:
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
        # can be set properly within the Rack application
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;

        # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
        # Comet/long-poll stuff.  It's also safe to set if you're
        # using only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx.
        # Otherwise you _want_ nginx to buffer responses to slow
        # clients, really.
        # proxy_buffering off;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server2;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what openssl has to say about www.CLIENTSITE.com:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.CLIENTSITE.com:443 -servername www.CLIENTSITE.com

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.OURSITE.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-- SNIP --
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.OURSITE.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4980 bytes and written 447 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: XYZ
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: ABC
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    -- SNIP --

    Start Time: 1473804850
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess you need to add CLIENTSITE.com (without www) too

Comment: @AlexeyTen -- the CNAME is from www.CLIENTSITE.com to CLIENT.OURSITE.com so afaik it never should it the server name CLIENTSITE.com

Answer (score 0):

According to the configuration you have specified the same certificate and key for `*.OURSITE.com;` and `www.CLIENTSITE.com`. So it works exactly how you have configured:

```
server {

    listen   443 ssl;
    server_name *.OURSITE.com;
    root /path/to/root/;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/OURSITE.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/OURSITE.key;
```

...

```
server {

    listen   443 ssl;
    server_name www.CLIENTSITE.com;
    root /path/to/root/;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/OURSITE.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/OURSITE.key;
```

Comment: Sorry about that -- I missed editing that in my obfuscated code. I just checked and I did use the right certs in the actual files.